# In python multi-producer & multi-consumer threading, may queue.join() be unreliable?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

A python multi-producer & multi-consumer threading pseudocode:

```
def threadProducer():
    while upstreams_not_done:
        data = do_some_work()
        queue_of_data.put(data)

def threadConsumer():
    while True:
        data = queue_of_data.get()
        do_other_work()
        queue_of_data.task_done()

queue_of_data = queue.Queue()

list_of_producers = create_and_start_producers()
list_of_consumers = create_and_start_consumers()

queue_of_data.join()
# is now all work done?
```

In which `queue_of_data.task_done()` is called for each item in queue.

When **producers work slower then consumers**, is there a possibility `queue_of_data.join()` **non-blocks at some moment when no producer generates data yet, but all consumers finish their tasks** by `task_done()`?

And if `Queue.join()` is not reliable like this, how can I check if all work done?

Comment: thread.join and Queue.join test different conditions and should be used for different purposes.   thread.join is only useful if the thread exits after emptying the queue.

Comment: `Queue.join()` is reliable for its intended use:  when all works items are queued before consumers start working.  Then (and only then) it's certain that "all queue items marked done" implies "all work is done".

Comment: thanks to @TimPeters , but if there are **too many items** from producer which may larger than RAM, there is no possible *queued before consumers start*, how can I do with multi-producer & multi-consumer threading?

Comment: @vbem, see my answer and its recent edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to put a sentinel value (like `None`) on the queue, one for each consumer thread, when producers are done.  Then consumers are written to exit the thread when it pulls `None` from the queue.

So, e.g., in the main program:

```
for t in list_of_producers:
    t.join()
# Now we know all producers are done.
for t in list_of_consumers:
    queue_of_data.put(None)  # tell a consumer we're done
for t in list_of_consumers:
    t.join()
```

and consumers look like:

```
def threadConsumer():
    while True:
        data = queue_of_data.get()
        if data is None:
            break
        do_other_work()
```

Note:  if producers can overwhelm consumers, create the queue with a maximum size.  Then `queue.put()` will block when the queue reaches that size, until a consumer removes something from the queue.

Comment: nice! with sentinel in queue, it seems threading.Lock, threading.RLock and etc. and no need any more.

Comment: When a straightforward use of a `Queue` is sufficient, by all means use just that.  The threading will be easy, obvious, and robust then.  Other gimmicks are better suited for other tasks.  For example, while a `Queue` _can_ be used (in a contorted way) to enforce mutual exclusion (e.g., to ensure only one thread is writing to the console), that's done much more obviously using a `with some_Lock:` block.

Comment: Be sure to call queue_of_data.task_done() before your consumer exits, otherwise queue_of_data.join() will hang forever.

`if data is None:
            queue_of_data.task_done()
            break`

Comment: @hackerfriendly, the pattern I suggest doesn't use `queue.join()` at all - and so no need to use `queue.task_done()` either.